# How do I rebuild the music library on my iphone?

Tags: iphone

Using iTunes, I updated album names and track numbers on my iPhone. But the music library is stuck using the old values. What gives? How can I get the iPhone music library to update?

I'm on iOS 5

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the music library on your phone got confused.

Remove the music from your phone and re-add it by

- either removing it manually (if you are managing manually)
- or unchecking music syncing in iTunes

Then sync once to clear the iPhone music library, add your music again and re-sync to relead.

If that doesn't work, backup your phone, restore to defaults, restore the backup, sync the phone. That will completely clear any cached data on the phone and allow it to sync "fresh" to iTunes.

Comment: Completely rebuilding my phone isn't a solution, that's the last resort.

Comment: A complete restore of your phone IS the solution. As noted above, removing and re-adding your music to the phone _may_ force a rebuild successfully, but if it doesn't you will need to do a restore. Apple does not provide any other way to rebuild the itunesdb on an iOS device; their intended support path is to backup and restore.